# Getting Emacs to open webpages in Iceweasel

Tags: browser, emacs, iceweasel

I'm trying to get Emacs to open webpages in Iceweasel. Following the instructions given [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseUrl), I've had Custom add the following lines to my `.emacs`:

```
'(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-default-browser))
'(browse-url-generic-program "iceweasel")
```

However, if I try something like `M-x browse-url` and then type in `www.google.com`, I get nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: A wild guess: perhaps set `browse-url-browser-function` to `browse-url-firefox`, and set `browse-url-firefox-program` to `"iceweasel"`?

Comment: How about using `start-process` -- e.g., `(start-process "process-name" "*OUTPUT-BUFFER*""/path/to/executable""argument-one""argument-two""argument-three")`  If you do not want an output buffer, that can be `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Iceweasel is a version of Firefox, try setting `browse-url-browser-function` to `browse-url-firefox`, and set `browse-url-firefox-program` to `"iceweasel"`.